# Appending dicts from loop to list

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been building this scraper (with some massive help from users here) to get data, and I've come to ahalt right at the end. Basically I want to generate a dict using the scraped information and append it to a list, but the final lists ends up being just the tail-end of my data instead of the entire thing. Here's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import math

#Defining important variables
path_driver = "C:/Users/CS330584/Documents/Documentos de Defesa da Concorrência/Automatização de Processos/chromedriver.exe"
website = "https://sat.sef.sc.gov.br/tax.NET/Sat.Dva.Web/ConsultaPublicaDevedores.aspx"
value_search = 300
final_table = []

#Opening the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver)
driver.get(website)
search_max = driver.find_element_by_id("Body_Main_Main_ctl00_txtTotalDevedores")
search_max.send_keys(value_search)
btn_consult = driver.find_element_by_id("Body_Main_Main_ctl00_btnBuscar")
btn_consult.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
pages = math.ceil(value_search/50)

#Loop to scrape data, store it into a dict and append to list to generate a dataframe later 
for i in range(2, pages+1):
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        cnpjs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView']/tbody/tr/td[1]")
        empresas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView']/tbody/tr/td[2]")
        dividas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView']/tbody/tr/td[3]")

        for z in range(len(empresas)):
            temp_data = {'CNPJ' : cnpjs[z].text,
                'Empresas' : empresas[z].text,
                'Divida' : dividas[z].text
                }
        final_table.append(temp_data)
        driver.execute_script(f"javascript:GridView_ScrollToTop('Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView');__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Body$Main$Main$grpDevedores$gridView','Page${i}')")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

How can I make it so the final_table list is the aggregate of the dicts generated in the loop ?

Comment: There's a lot of code here for what sounds like a simple problem.  Can you reduce it down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you do what @defladamouse advises, I think you'll see your `final_table.append(temp_data)` line is only adding the last one because you don't do it inside the `for z in range(len(empresas)):`, I think?

Answer (score 1):

```
final_table.append(temp_data)
```

must be inside the your 'for' loop.

Correct the indentation of that line.